# How case class inherent class(not abstract) method and value? (scala)

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance

I have a Base class have some function and val, I want to inherent them in my inherent case class how to do it   ?
This is my base class:

```
class Base(val name:String, val number:int) extends Sometrait {

   def copy(name:String=this.name, number:int=this.number){
       new Base(name, number)
   }
}
```

I want to write the:

```
case class SomeCase(val name:String, val number:int, val id:int)extends Base(String, number){
...
}
```

But the compiler always told me:

```
value **** needs `override' modifier    social.scala    /scalatest/src/scalatest    line 35 Scala
```

But I really want to is just do as inherent not override, how to do it.

(I need to put the child class as case class, as it is easy for me to use in slick. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134425/how-to-write-class-and-tableclass-mapping-for-slick2-instead-of-using-case-class) is my another question for how to use class as table content class in slick, someone give me really great answer, but I still mass.))

Answer (score 0):

Because `name` and `number` fields in both `Base` and `SomeCase` are defined with `val` without any modifiers like `private`, they are both public members and participate in inheritance. Because these fields have same names in base and child classes, you have to add `override` modifier before `val name` and `val number` in the child class:

```
case class SomeCase(override val name: String, 
                    override val number: Int,
                    val id: Int) extends Base(name, number) { ... }
```